# Using QtMobility/Location, a Symbian Qt C++ application runs in emulator but not on device

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, location

I have a Symbian Qt C++ mobile application that runs fine in the emulator but when the application is compiled into a SIS file and installed on the phone, it installs successfully but does not start and fails silently without any message.

The application uses QtMobility 1.0.1 to access the Location API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found that the issue I'm facing is related to the following bug:** https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTMOBILITY-360

which is caused by using Qt Mobility 1.0.1 APIs, which are linked against a library (LBT) that is not available on Symbian 5th edition devices (but will be available on Symbian^3)

When I reverted to using the Qt Mobility 1.0.0 APIs on the device, the application started successfully.

The bug report states that it has been fixed in version 1.0.2 of the Qt Mobility APIs, but it hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 1):

Qt Mobility 1.0.2 was released last night.  See http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/07/27/qt-mobility-102-released/.